# .htaccess rewrite does not trigger on main URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two different domains who I want to point to separate folders on my server.

This .htaccess file is what I have currently

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/index.html [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/index.html [R,L]
```

*(Note that the [R] option is only there so I can see what is (not) happening while testing)*

It works fine if one goes to **www.foo.com/asdf** or **www.bar.com/something** 
However, simply going to **www.foo.com**  or **www.bar.com** (with or without the www. subdomain) won't trigger these rules for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is happening due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` failing for your home page (index.php or index.html) since either of those files will be found. You set your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /foo/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\. /foo/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /bar/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\. /bar/index.html [L]
```